# Appending data to a text file beyond cat

Tags: write

`cat` is a convenient way to append data to a text file.  Could I do better?

Comment: What do you mean with "better"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tee -a filename` also appends to files.
If that isn't what you want, you'll have to explain "better".

Comment: Better in terms of speed.

Comment: tee and cat should have similar performance, and it would be hard to beat them.